# why js is faster than c. why js faster calculates strings

Tags: javascript, c, string, performance, optimization

why this performs faster in js than in c

```js
console.time("done");
let x= "baobab"; 
for(let i = 0; i < 999999999; i++) (x = "baobab"); 
console.timeEnd("done");
```

result in browser: "done: 1482.992919921875 ms"
result in node: "done: 1.446s"

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
  char *x = "baobab";
  clock_t start, end;
  start = clock();
  for (int i = 0; i < 999999999; i++)
  {
    x = "baobab";
  }
  end = clock();
  double cpu_time_used = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("The process took %f seconds to execute\n", cpu_time_used);
return 0;
}
```

result: "The process took 1.565736 seconds to execute"

I've used gcc:

```bash
gcc -g ./src/main.c -o ./dist/program && echo 'compiled' && ./dist/program
```

what i'm trying to get: faster code or answer why js is faster in this task

Comment: Did you compile the C program with any optimization flag like `-O`? And to answer your question: in general, (optimized) C code is _way_ faster than JS.

Comment: A smart C compiler (**your** compiler is smart enough) will simply ignore the loop. Compile with optimizations turned on, vary the loop value and check for yourself :-)

Comment: voting to close. see [When code optimization happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142321/when-code-optimization-happens) or [How many GCC optimization levels are there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778538/how-many-gcc-optimization-levels-are-there) or the docs [Options That Control Optimization](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) or clang [Clang optimization levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548023/clang-optimization-levels)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/e4vEePqsq: The process took 0.000001 seconds to execute (exactly because the whole loop was optimized out because it doesn't do anything).

Comment: i've used gcc
gcc -g ./src/main.c -o ./dist/program && echo 'compiled' && ./dist/program
and still why this calculation is faster in js (ignoring it's useless)

Comment: So gcc defaults to compile fast, but run slow. You have to ask it to make the code run fast, for example using `-O2`.

Comment: Yogi okay thanks i understand. (:

Comment: I like the [femtosecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Femtosecond) resolution of "1482.992 919 921 875 ms".